# Tenses agreement..Have/had..and how backshifting works

Tags: conditional-constructions, perfect-constructions, backshifting

> It'd be great if you showed me the paintings you **had drawn**.
>
> It'd be great if you showed me the paintings you **have drawn**.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?

Should I backshift when constructing hypothetical sentences,or when I'm using past tense to be polite?

What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: I prefer the second one greatly.

Comment: As an aside, we don't normally use commas in a sentence like **It would be great if you...**

Comment: The verb "showed" is a *preterite* (has a past-tense form), but it does not really refer to the past. This preterite form indicates "modal remoteness", because we have a conditional construction ("if - then"). The author of the sentence is unsure whether that guy would really show the paintings. Thus, there's no need for backshifting. A good question, by the way. It **will** be great if someone **gives** a clear answer.

Comment: The modal remoteness invoked by "would be ... if" does not affect the tense of the verb in the reduced clause *you had|have drawn*; if affects only the verb **showed**. The reduced clause could have "you will draw, you drew, you are drawing, you have drawn, you had drawn" as context requires.

Comment: @TRomano, take a look at the question i posted here a few hours ago. 
IT concerns the same topic

Comment: @lekon chekon: where?

Answer (score 2):

> It'd be great if you showed me the paintings you had drawn.

In Sentence #1, *You Had Drawn* is Past Perfect, and *Showed* is also past tense. In order for verb-tense agreement, and formality, *be* also needs to be past-tense. The sentence then becomes:

> It would have been great if you showed me the painting you had drawn.

If you are in The Present, and you want to see the paintings this person *had drawn*, you would use Sentence #2.

If you are in the present, and it comes about that there are paintings you *have not seen* and therefore cannot comment on, then Sentence #1 is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a subtle difference in meaning, for me, is:

> It'd be great if you showed me the paintings you **had drawn** (last year).

You drew the paintings, went on to something else, and are now going back to them to show me what you did.

> It'd be great if you showed me the paintings you **have drawn** (today).

You recently drew something and want to review it, for example a teacher asking: "Show me what you **have drawn** in class", as opposed to, "Show me what you **had drawn** as a 5 years old."  Using **drew** loses this subtlety.

> It'd be great if you showed me the paintings you **drew**.

BTW, some people may argue that paintings are not drawn...